# snakemake: official way to list Python dependencies of .smk files themselves?

Tags: snakemake

EDIT: we started actually [adding anyconfig support](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/pull/1111) in Snakemake itself.

---

Is there an official standardized way to specify a python module dpendencies that is imported by the .smk files themselves - as opposed to used by the rules?

As part of a modernization and overhaul of [our pipeline](https://cbg-ethz.github.io/V-pipe/), we're considering using [python anyconfig module](https://github.com/ssato/python-anyconfig) to support multiple configuration formats in our workflow. (The goal being: we can support [.yaml/.json files as the current standard](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/configuration.html#snakefiles-standard-configuration), but also [the .ini style that our older users have used in the past](https://github.com/cbg-ethz/V-pipe/wiki/options) - and [for which in the past we used](https://github.com/cbg-ethz/V-pipe/blob/master/rules/config_default.smk) python configparser module).

So that's a conda-forge package that needs to be installed into the same environment where snakemake is and from which the workflow will be loaded, so the configuration could be processed.
(as opposed to a specific rules' conda environment .yaml which installs the bioinformatics tools needed to run steps of the workflow).

This is basically the same situation as someone following the official [recomendations about tabular data and importing pandas](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/configuration.html#tabular-configuration) but which isn't part of the [snakemake-minimal](https://github.com/bioconda/bioconda-recipes/blob/master/recipes/snakemake/meta.yaml) installation.

Would [an environment.yaml file in the base directory as done by the tutorial](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake-tutorial-data/blob/master/environment.yaml) be considered good practice?
e.g.: something that could automatically be picked up by future version of snakedeploy?

Or is it discouraged to rely on anything that isn't a dependency of snakemake-minimal (e.g: yaml) or snakemake (e.g: pandas) ?

Thanks!